# Use TCP/IP before OS booted

Tags: bootloader

I have tried to find ways to actually send and recieve data from a remote computer before the OS is booted with windows boootloader. Is there any way I can send or recieve data with TCP/P before the OS is fully booted up?

Answer (score 2):

There are several viable solutions. The easiest is to look at something like the PXE toolkit http://pxe-toolkit.sourceforge.net/web-site.html

It's quite powerful, and can probably do what you wish to do.

There are options, look at the bootp protocol.  have a look at the following project as well:

http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=423

Comment: As far as I understand PXE something I need to install. I just want all the original stuff and be able to send. I talked with a freind and he told me I actually need to code all the drivers and tcp stack too send and recv.